# Javascript - Agregar simbolo de coma (,) a <span> con replace();

Tags: javascript, regex

He visto esta pregunta en ingles [Javascript - add a span for each letter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17464864/javascript-add-a-span-for-each-letter) y siguiendo los comentarios he logrado que mis palabras se agreguen perfectamente a etiquetas `<span>` a las cuales les agrego una animación de *Entrada* y *Salida*.

Lo que pasa es que mi carácter coma (,) no lo reconoce como letra y por lo tanto esta animación que tienen los `<span>` no la incluye y la animación no se ve bien. [animación](https://ibb.co/JkS9rF4)

En consola me muestra como texto.
[image: console]

**Lo que he intentado:**

Quise agregar el Unicode de la coma (,) que es -002C dentro del rango de caracteres permitidos, pero ni aun así me la reconoce.

**código original:**
JS:

```
        $('.index-copy .letter-row-1, .index-copy .letter-row-2').each(function(){
            $(this).html($(this).text().replace(/([^\x00-\x80]|\w)/g, "<span class='letter'>$&</span>"));
        });
```

HTML:

```
<div class="index-copy">
    <h2 class="letter-row-1" style="font-size: 40px!important">NO ABANDONES LO QUE TE HACE ÚNICO,</h2>
    <h2 class="letter-row-2" style="font-size: 40px!important">REFUERZA TU MARCA</h2>*texto en itálica*
</div>
```

**código con unicode de la coma (,) agregado:**

```
        $('.index-copy .letter-row-1, .index-copy .letter-row-2').each(function(){
            $(this).html($(this).text().replace(/([^\x00-\x80-\002]|\w)/g, "<span class='letter'>$&</span>"));
        });
```

Cualquier comentario sobre como lograr solucionar esto lo agradeceria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En la `RegEx`:

```
[^\x00-\x80-\002]
```

No estas agregando la coma, sino que la estas excluyendo (*[mas info](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Groups_and_Ranges#tipos)*).

### Solución 1:

Si lo que buscas es que todo caracter distinto de *["vacio"](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Character_Classes#tipos)* sea agregado agregado dentro de un `<span`, podrías hacerlo así:

```
/[^\s]/g
```

**Demo:**

```js
$('.index-copy .letter-row-1, .index-copy .letter-row-2').each(function() {
  $(this).html($(this).text().replace(/[^\s]/g, "<span class='letter'>$&</span>"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="index-copy">
  <h2 class="letter-row-1" style="font-size: 40px!important">NO ABANDONES LO QUE TE HACE ÚNICO,</h2>
  <h2 class="letter-row-2" style="font-size: 40px!important">REFUERZA TU MARCA</h2>
</div>
```

---

#### Solución 2:

Si quisieras mantener tu `RegEx` y solo agregar la coma, podrías hacerlo así:

```
/([^\x00-\x80]|\w|,)/g
```

**Demo:**

```js
$('.index-copy .letter-row-1, .index-copy .letter-row-2').each(function() {
  $(this).html($(this).text().replace(/([^\x00-\x80]|\w|,)/g, "<span class='letter'>$&</span>"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="index-copy">
  <h2 class="letter-row-1" style="font-size: 40px!important">NO ABANDONES LO QUE TE HACE ÚNICO,</h2>
  <h2 class="letter-row-2" style="font-size: 40px!important">REFUERZA TU MARCA</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta @Marcos, agregando `/([^\x00-\x80]|\w|,)/g` para incluir la coma me soluciona en mi caso porque estoy seguro de no agregar otro caracter.

Answer (score 1):

No necesitas una expresión regular para separar por `<span>` cada letra del elemento, para ello, te propongo que uses [`String.prototype.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), el cual te separa el string por partes, de manera que podemos separar el string y obtener un array de cada letra de él, array el cual vamos a recorrer con [`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```js
$(".index-copy > h2").each(i => {
  const el = $(".index-copy > h2")[i];
  const split = $(el).text().split("");
  $(el).html("");
  split.forEach(w => {
    el.innerHTML += `<span class="letter" style="transform: scale(0.25) rotateZ(0deg);">${w}</span>`;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="index-copy">
    <h2 class="letter-row-1" style="font-size: 40px!important">NO ABANDONES LO QUE TE HACE ÚNICO,</h2>
    <h2 class="letter-row-2" style="font-size: 40px!important">REFUERZA TU MARCA</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Si bien la idea esta bien, es mas eficiente hacer `$(el).html(valor);` una sola vez. De lo contrario estas obligando al navegador a hacer el re-calculo de `layout`, `repainting` y/o `rendering` cada vez que actualizas el `DOM`

Comment: @anythingg muchas gracias por tu respuesta, voy a implementarlo en mi otra seccion de `contactenos` porque me parece muy buena idea.